# How can I make alternate clicks change the background of a div within a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to alternate the background colors of a div within a button using mouse clicks.

I only managed to make it work on first click by adding `onclick="document.getElementById('nrOne').style.background = 'black'"`  to the 
`<button id="btn1">` element.

```
<button id="btn1">

<div class="container-heading">
    <div class="container-number" id="nrOne">
        <h1> 01 </h1>
     </div>
    <div class="container-text">
        ...
    </div>
```

Any help or tips is highly appreciated. Thank you StackOverflow!

Comment: Are you just toggling between black and the standard colour? Also, you've tagged this question with jQuery - are you looking for a jQuery solution?

Comment: Just toggle a class. `document.getElementById('nrOne').classList.toggle('dark')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use toggle method. Attach it to button and then create two functions that will be call altenate:

```
$("#btn1").toggle(function(){
    $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#000000" });
}, function(){
    $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#FF0000" });
});
```

And without toggle method but click method:

```
var t = true;
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    if(t){
        t = false;
        $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#000000" });
    }
    else{
        t = true;
        $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#FF0000" });
    }
});
```

Comment: I will update code with another solution without toggle

Comment: also, if i'm correct you can write it like this t = !t;  t  ? $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#000000" }) : $("#nrOne").css({ "background-color": "#FF0000" });  . Bit less boiler :P

Comment: I don't know if you can use ternary without assign the result, but I think no. By the way, in my opinion, without ternary and `t = !t`, it's more readable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without jQuery

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="changeBackgroundColor(this)">

        function changeBackgroundColor(src)
        {
           document.getElementById("nrOne").style.background = 'black' // put some condition and change the color
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's a pure jQ implementation which uses `toggleClass` to simply add/remove a class on each successive click:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#nrOne').toggleClass('black');
})
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Click me</button>

<div class="container-heading">
  <div class="container-number" id="nrOne">
    <h1>01</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-text">
    <h1>02</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This suppose that `nrOne` have an initial color

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying so quickly! I wasn't expecting such a helpful community, this was my first post ever ! I already love you all and this awesome site!!

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the same, using only javaScript. (Here you can add as many colors as you want to the array and loop over them by clicking the button.)

```
var box = document.getElementById('div-of-which-you-want-the-color-to-change'),
        button = document.getElementById('button-with-event-handler'),
        indexOfChosenColor = 0;

button.onclick = function(){

        var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];

        box.style.backgroundColor = colors[indexOfChosenColor%colors.length];
        indexOfChosenColor++;

}
```